# image does not appear on top of a label

Tags: html, css, playframework

I want to add an image to a label, but the image doesn't appear. I use the play framework.

What I'm trying to do, is put an image instead of a checkbox where the image plays the role of a checkbox.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    opacity:0;
    height: 16px;
    width: 17px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label{
    background-image: url("/assets/images/help.jpg");
    height: 16px;
    width: 17px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
    background-image: url("/assets/images/help.jpg");
    height: 16px;
    width: 17px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox_wrapper navbar-text navbar-right font-size-8pt margin-bottom-0px"><input type="checkbox" id="enable-help"><label></label></label>
```

Comment: i can't see any output

Comment: yhh that is the problem. the image does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Seams to be working ...

Maybe the url to your images is wrong, or height and width is too small...

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    opacity:0;
    height: 459px;
    width: 459px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label{
    background-image: url("http://image005.flaticon.com/55/svg/61/61221.svg");
    height: 459px;
    width: 459px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
    background-image: url("http://image005.flaticon.com/55/svg/61/61141.svg");
    height: 459px;
    width: 459px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox_wrapper navbar-text navbar-right font-size-8pt margin-bottom-0px"><input type="checkbox" id="enable-help"><label></label></label>
```

Comment: Open the dev tools and see if you get a a 404 response for "/assets/images/help.jpg".

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you use the same image for checked and unchecked state...

Answer (score 0):

Your code works with correct image paths

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/79m1hy6d/1/)

```
input[type="checkbox"] + label{
    background-image: url("http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1");
    height: 255px;
    width: 255px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
    background-image: url("http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/255/200/2");
    height: 200px;
    width: 255px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

Comment: I think the case is about paths of images because your code is working

Comment: is there a specific way to give the img url in play?

Comment: I don't know play framework but check with the browser inspector the path of your images. Here is the issue. As you can see in the JSFiddle I've provide, it works fine with good image paths

Comment: Can we see a live example ? It's very difficult to help you debugging your code without seeing it exactly and in my example it works so..